# How to calculate the size of URL image and create `UICollectionCell` based on image size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have used `CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout`. What I do is loading images in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` using block by sending asynchronous request. Everything is fine here, but I want dynamic collection view cell. I will have custom cell containing image,text and bottom view for displaying share button.

How can I calculate the size of URL image as image is downloaded and displayed in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` which is called after `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`.

Coding for loading images in `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` takes too much time. What is the best way?

Comment: have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Very normal tip would be - If you are working with API that can give you size of image , that will a immediate help and can be used in sizeForItem method.

Comment: yes, if the API can give me the height and width, it will be easy but my Sir told me that JSON response will get bigger. So I have to figure out in the coding myself.